# How can I solve Spring Security config

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, xml-parsing

I want to integrate spring-Security to myapp (I use Spring MVC)

I can't understand these problems:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'beans:beans' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'http' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'session-management' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'autentication-manager'.
```

Below is the XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans              
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

   <!-- Global Security Settings -->
   <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

   <http auto-config="true">
      <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?time=1">
         <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?time=1" />
      </session-management>
      <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login.do" default-target-url="/home" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?err=1" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
      <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?out=1" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
      <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('10000_10000')" />
   </http>

   <!-- Authentication Providers for Form Login -->
   <autentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginService">
         <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
      </authentication-provider>
   </autentication-manager>

   <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
   <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />

   <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
   <beans:bean id="LoginService" class="com.pfe.service.imp.LoginServiceImp" />
   <!-- ADD THE DATASOURCES HERE -->
</beans:beans>
```

Below is the exception stack trace.

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 24 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 29; cvc-complex-type.2.3 : L'élément 'session-management' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère, car le type porte le type de contenu "element-only".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 29; cvc-complex-type.2.3 : L'élément 'session-management' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère, car le type porte le type de contenu "element-only".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 22 more

juil. 21, 2015 8:35:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
juil. 21, 2015 8:35:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/TRyGED] suite aux erreurs précédentes
juil. 21, 2015 8:35:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
juil. 21, 2015 8:35:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5723)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please post your security XML config file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of errors pops up where ever there is any improper parsing of XML files. Eclipse tries to validate these files and gives **cvc-complex-type.2.3** errors.

If you have copied these configurations from somewhere then there are possibilities of having some invisible strange characters in between spaces, line breaks & at various places.

Try to remove all spaces & new line/carriage return characters from your file and save the file.

If you are working on Linux environment, then below command will detect these invisible characters in your XML configurations which my be causing problems.

```
cat -v /path/to/file-name.xml
```

You can also use any advance text editors, like BBEdit, NotePad++, etc, to detect these characters.

Comment: Yes ! , I rewrite the file

Comment: Could you please then mark this answer as the correct answer?